# Why clientRight or clientBottom are not exist in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, web

As you know `clientLeft` returns the border in `PXs`, and you know there are `clientLeft` and `clientTop`,
So why `clientRight` and `clientButtom` are not exist in JavaScript?
and how to get the `Right` and `buttom` Border in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate "offsetRight" by subtracting an element's offsetWidth and offsetLeft from its parent's offsetWidth. Similarly, you can calculate "offsetBottom" by subtracting an element's offsetHeight and offsetTop from its parent's offsetHeight. My guess as to why there is only an offsetLeft and offsetTop is that an element is positioned relative to its origin point: the distance from its parent's top left corner along an X and Y axis, the default being (0,0). Offset therefore retrieves these two coordinates.

```js
const square = document.getElementById("square"); 
const parent = document.getElementById("parent");

const offsetTop = square.offsetTop;
const offsetLeft = square.offsetLeft;

const offsetHeight = square.offsetHeight;
const offsetWidth = square.offsetWidth; 

const parentWidth = parent.offsetWidth;
const parentHeight = parent.offsetHeight;

const offsetBottom = parentHeight - offsetHeight - offsetTop;
const offsetRight = parentWidth - offsetWidth - offsetLeft;

console.log("top:", offsetTop, "left:", offsetLeft,"right:", offsetRight, "bottom:", offsetBottom);
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
#parent {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#square {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
<div id="square"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: the question mentions 'clientRight' and 'clientBottom', so why use the terms 'offsetRight' and 'offsetBottom'?

Comment: the question states that 'clientRight' and 'clientBottom' do not exist in javascript, and asks 1. why this is and 2. how to get these values by another means; 'offsetRight' and 'offsetBottom' is how you do that

Comment: the question is how to get the right and bottom border of an element, which is what one would imagine clientRight and clientBottom to give, assuming they are similar to clientTop and clientLeft. the offset properties do something entirely different

Comment: he is saying clientRight and clientBottom do not exist in javascript: "So why clientRight and clientButtom are not exist in JavaScript?" and he is correct, they do not exist in javascript and therefor cannot be used to get the right and bottom border of an element.